# How to use pNFS in NFSv4.1

Tags: linux, nfs, linux-kernel, nfs4

As I know, `pNFS` is an extended protocol over `NFSv4.1`. So, I have two questions:

- How to use `pNFS` in `NFSv4.1`?
- Is there any special requirement for kernel version in server side?

Answer (score 3):

The client support exists since linux kernel 2.6.39, but part of it was backported to RHEL6 servers as well. IOW, any modern client will support pnfs as soon as server will advertise it. The main requirement to use NFSv4.1/pNFS is capable server. Known server:

- Linux 4.0, block layout
- NetApp 8.1, file layout
- [dCache](https://www.dcache.org/), file layout
- [Ganesha NFS](http://nfs-ganesha.github.io/), file layout (and possibly more)